# Shell script succeeds in Ubuntu but fails in Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

Does anyone know why this command, when executed in a shell script, succeeds in Ubuntu but fails with "Error: Unrecognized option: -c" in Amazon Linux 2? I realize it's with the /bin/bash part most likely, but completely stumped what the issue is beyond *something* about the double quotes...

```
docker run --rm --name graal -v $(pwd):/${PROJECT_NAME} ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image:ol8-java11-22.2.0 \
/bin/bash -c "gu install native-image; \
              native-image \
                -H:EnableURLProtocols=http \
                            -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=/${PROJECT_NAME}/reflect.json \
                -jar /${PROJECT_NAME}/target/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}.jar \
                ; \
                mkdir /${PROJECT_NAME}/target/custom-runtime \
                ; \
                cp ${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION} /${PROJECT_NAME}/target/custom-runtime/${PROJECT_NAME}";
```

Comment: That's not how bash reports a bad option. It says "/bin/bash: -c: invalid option" followed by a multi-line usage message that lists all the options. So you're not actually running `bash` there.

Comment: This might be a better fit for [unix.se] or [sf], to find people familiar with the Amazon LInux environment.

Comment: @Barmar interesting, ok that's a hint maybe, thanks for the quick reply

Comment: What do you see if you do `file /bin/bash` or `/bin/bash --version` on Amazon?

Comment: @Barmar GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-koji-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: @Barmar for Ubuntu I get: GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: I only have access to bash 3 and bash 5, but they produce the same style of error, so I don't see why bash 4 would be different. I think the error is coming from something else.

Comment: I think for some reason `docker` thinks that `-c` is its own option, not an option to /bin/bash`

Comment: yes, maybe `\-c`, or `\\\-c` or similar may quote so `docker` doesn't "see" it as an option. Also, figure out what is the smallest amount of code that reproduces this error message and then post to https://unix.stackexchange.com ?  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `CMD` (`bash -c "..."`) passed as an argument to the entrypoint of `ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image`.
Depending on said entrypoint, that could explain why `-c` is not recognized.

For testing, you can instead try and override the [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime), to check if your `bash` command is better recognized.

And I would put the script commands in a script file, in pwd, mounted in `/${PROJECT_NAME}`.

So:

```
docker run --rm --name graal -v $(pwd):/${PROJECT_NAME} \
  --entrypoint "bash -c /${PROJECT_NAME}/myscript.sh" \
  ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image:ol8-java11-22.2.0
```